# Accessing jQuery IDs with for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, for-loop, append

I have a simple problem and hopefully a simple answer.

So, I have a `JSON` file which I'm utilizing that has a ton of data in it. I'm trying to make a slideshow with such data, which is built, but I'm having trouble appending the proper information to the slides without hard coding everything.

My idea is to use a `for` loop to target specific IDs (slides), but I can't for the life of me figure out how to target each item for the loop.

I was thinking something like this, which is not working at all lol.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {
        $('#slide(i)').append("<p>Hello World</p>");
    }
})();
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="slide0"></div>
<div id="slide1"></div>
<div id="slide2"></div>
<div id="slide3"></div>
<div id="slide4"></div>
<div id="slide5"></div>
<div id="slide6"></div>
<div id="slide7"></div>
<div id="slide8"></div>
<div id="slide9"></div>
</body>
```

**As far as actually targeting individual slides, any syntax I try I can't get it to go.**

*Any help is appreciated!*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use string concatenation

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        //use string concatenation
        $('#slide' + i).append("<p>Hello World</p>");
    }
});//also there is no () here... it is not a IIFE... it is a callback registration which will be invoked by jQuery when dom ready is fired
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mWEfN/)

Comment: How weird, that was the first thing I tried... must've missed a quote somewhere :-P Thanks!

Comment: Regarding your added comment, I was always taught by running self invoking functions with different languages involved it was good practice to document the language used? })(jQuery); for example. Is that wrong?

Comment: @NicholasHazel your implementation was wrong... see the update to get the same effect without a IIFE...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mWEfN/2/ That should work quite nicely with my JSON now that I know what was wrong. Thanks a ton!